# Insert multiple rows with single dynamic data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert same data for multiple rows with different `@EmpId` into table.

Query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SaveEmployee
    (@EmpIds varchar(50),  //1,2,3,4
     @StateId int,
     @CountryId int,
     @Comments varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.tblEmpDetails (EmpId, StateId, CountryId, Comments)
        SELECT * 
        FROM [dbo].[FN_ListToTable] (',',@EmpIds)

    -- How can I add this: (@StateId, @CountryId, @Comments)
END
```

Or is there any other better way to handle this?

Comment: Add those values to your `SELECT` clause. If you got out of the bad habit of using `*` and explicitly defined your columns, you'd realise how trivial it is to include a variable in a `SELECT` clause.

Comment: On a different note, why are you using a user function to split the list when there is `STRING_SPLIT` or better yet, why not use a table type parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define the correct columns in the *select* list:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblEmpDetails (EmpId, StateId, CountryId, Comments)
SELECT [<ReturnedColumn>], @StateId, @CountryId, @Comments
from dbo.FN_ListToTable (',', @EmpIds);
```

Also note that SQL Server has a built-in *string_split()* function.